# How to check if wifi is on Hotspot (AP) mode

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, wifi-hotspot

I am trying to find out the current mode of wlan0 interface. Is there any command or way, so that I can find out if a hotspot is running or if WIFI running in my RPI 3.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain how you set up the hotspot in the first place.  Beyond that `ip link show wlan0` should give you some information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the output of `iwconfig wlan0` look for whether `Mode` is set to `Managed` (the standard mode) or not (possibly running as a hotspot).

Comment: it is giving me the following value when hotspot mode is on `wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=31 dBm` and if it is connected to WIFI then this is the output  `Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 14:CC:20:AD:82:16` .